# Issue with "Resolution" field in a Jira Story/Bug

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I am trying to Complete a Sprint for our JIRA Project. And It tells me that all the issues are incomplete.
On diving deeper I found out that even though the status for the issues is "Resolved" their Resolution field says "Unresolved".
I read that we can Add "Post Functions" to transitions but I am not able to find the field. 
All I can see is a "Properties" tag, which does not allow me to add a Post function anywhere.
Please help me what should I do to fix this, since I will be unable to close the sprint.

Comment: Is the Resolution field present on the screen associated to the transition that leads to the "Resolved" status?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: You must open the workflow used for that project and issue type. Then you must check the transition from the previous state to "Resolved". There you will find "Transition View:" followed by the name of your screen. Click on that.

Comment: Cant find it -> I Go To Adminitration - Issues - Workflow Schemes -> Where I see the option to Edit/Copy a Scheme associated with each Issue Type. I dont see "Transition View" either in Diagram View or in the Text View in Editable mode.

Comment: No, the workflow scheme is a different thing. Try this: go to Administration, Projects, find your project, then click on "Issue Types" (by the way, I'm still on Jira 5.2.11, so it might be different if you have another version). There you can click on the Workflow for your issue type. Or, from the Workflow schemes, just find the one assigned to your project, and check the mapping between your issue type and workflow, and click on that workflow.

Comment: Yes, my state matches. The problem is I need that when the user Moves an Issue to field status "Resolved" the issue field "Resolution" should be marked as "Done"

Answer (score 1):

In JIRA an issue is only resolved when it has a value in the resolution field. Even if the issue status is 'Resolved' or 'Closed' it won't matter if the resolution field does not have a value.

Unfortunately this means that if you play around with your workflow it is possible to create transitions to 'Resolved' or 'Closed' that do not add a value to the resolution field. When you do this it is easy to end up with issues with a status of 'Resolved' or 'Closed' that aren't really resolved and these will stop you completing a sprint.

A simple workaround to this problem is to fix your workflow. Then you re-open the issues that are causing a problem and then resolve them again.

The workflow can be fixed in two ways:

Make sure the transition to 'Resolved' or 'Closed' is associated with the 'Resolve Issue Screen'. You do this by editing the workflow, selecting the transition and then editing it.

The other method is to add a post function. Once again you edit your workflow and select the transition. Once selected you should see a box of information that includes 'Properties', 'Triggers', 'Conditions', 'Validators' and 'Post Functions'. If you click on 'Post Functions' you will be able to add a new post function that updates the resoultion field with a value (it doesn't matter what the value is).

[This Atlassian page explains more about advanced configuration of workflows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver070/advanced-workflow-configuration-749383189.html?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconfluence.atlassian.com%2Fadminjiraserver070%2Fadvanced-workflow-configuration-749383189.html&application=cac)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from Workflow edit menu. You have to edit transition configuration adding a post function called: "Set Field Value to constant or Groovy expression"

So you add this function to the Resolve transition, and set it to modify Resolved value to "Done"

regards

Comment: Yes there are loads of links to add a Post Function but the problem is i don't see it anywhere on my jira administration panel.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It is provided by this plugin. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.innovalog.jmwe.jira-misc-workflow-extensions/server/pricing It is not expensive, but it isnt free...

Answer (score 0):

Akshat, if you 
- go to your board, 
- then to board's configuration (top right corner - Board - Configure) 
- then select Columns section on the left pane
- then check if the rightmost column (called "Done") has the statuses you expect to be ending statuses
- then check if [x] Set Resolution checkmark is On?

Comment: I have a custom definition of the columns, also a custom workflow and workflow scheme as well. But I dont see a checkbox to set resolution anywhere.